# Want to make A CSS if meta key value is empty

Tags: custom-field, widgets

I made a widget using custom fields.

Now I want to hide it if the first field meta key has no value.

I can do it using

```
if empty $mykey 
<script type="text/javascript>
#showbox {display:none;}
</script>
endif
```

I don't know PHP. So I am confused. 
I am calling the value of the meta keys this way

```
<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mykey', true ) ); ?>
```

Here is the widget output code .

```
// Create the widget output.
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $prod_image_url = get_post_meta( 'prod_image_url' );


    echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $args['after_title']; ?>
    <?php
    if( is_single() ):
        ?>
        <div id="show">
            <img class="prodimage" src="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'prod_image_url', true ) ); ?>"/><br>
        </div>
        <?php
    else:
        echo '';
    endif;
    ?>
```

This widget easily is shown only on single posts.

What i am trying to do is

if the value of prod_image_url is empty
do that CSS to hide that

Answer (score 0):

you won't need css for that

```
// Create the widget output.
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$prod_image_url = get_post_meta( 'prod_image_url' );
if(!empty($prod_image_url)){
echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $args['after_title']; 

if( is_single() ):
    ?>
    <div id="show">
        <img class="prodimage" src="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'prod_image_url', true ) ); ?>"/><br>
    </div>
    <?php
else:
    echo '';
endif;
}
?>
```

For any professional help you can consider checking out : [PSD to Wordpress](http://www.psdtohtmlcloud.com/psd-to-wordpress)

Comment: Please merge your answers into one.